# Invalid Procedure Call on DateDiff with MS Access Driver

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003, datediff

The following query:

```
SELECT DateDiff('month',0,'2000-01-01 00:00:00');
```

Returns a "[ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid procedure call" error, with the bizarre code of 22018.

Specs:

- Microsoft Access Driver version: 4.00.6305.00
- Database created with Access 2003

The above appears to be the proper syntax, as calling the function with the current format (no single quotes for month), returns "[Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Too few parameters. Expected 1."

So, what is the proper syntax, if I did not get it right? Alternatively, how do I perform a datediff with that version of the driver?

Comment: For future reference, here's good documentation with a list of accepted date parts: http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/datediff.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand how ODBC is involved, but your query won't work in a pure Access context because DateDiff requires "m" as the interval argument for month.

Within Access 2003, this query returns 1201:

```
SELECT DateDiff('m',0,'2000-01-01 00:00:00');
```